# Django Haystack/Elasticsearch dwithin only returns one SearchResult. Expect several

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using Django Haystack alongside Elasticsearch. Whereas ElasticSearch can perform a distance query and return 11 results for a 5 mile radius, Haystack's dwithin method only returns one result for the same criteria. Below is the search query I use in my form.

```
def search(self):
    if not self.is_valid():
        return self.no_query_found()

    if not self.cleaned_data['q']:
        return self.no_query_found()

    sqs = self.searchqueryset.all()


    distance = D(mi=5)

    obj= Geo.objects.get(zip_code=self.cleaned_data['q'])

    latitude = obj.latitude
    longitude = obj.longitude

    center_point = Point(longitude, latitude)

    sqs = sqs.dwithin('location', center_point, distance)

    if self.load_all:
        sqs.load_all()
        return sqs
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer. If you take a string input, you need to convert it to an int, then multiply by 1000. The first part makes sense. The last part is not documented, so here you go.